# Entering a function into the dialog box of Deducer package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to know how can I enter the below function which is a very useful function to mark the very ends of whiskers of the boxplots in ggplot2 under R (get_tails function) into the dialog box of Deducer package. Hint, the dialog box is under the geometric elements - points - e.g. x = drv y=hwy (for reproducibility), summary, options change to custom, there you would find a dialog box to enter a function

```
#Load the library
library(ggplot2)
library(Deducer)

data(mpg)

#Create a function to calculate the points

#a built-in function that does this

get_tails = function(x) {
    q1 = quantile(x)[2]
    q3 = quantile(x)[4]
    iqr = q3 -q1
    upper = q3+1.5*iqr
    lower = q1-1.5*iqr

    #Trim upper and lower
    up = max(x[x < upper])
    lo = min(x[x > lower])
    return(c(lo, up)
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=drv,y=hwy)) + geom_boxplot( width=0.5) + 
    stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y= get_tails, pch=4, size=3, colour="red")
```

this will give this result (this is just a reproducible example of mpg dataset):

![Boxplots with 'x' marks at the ends of the two whiskers][1]

Please how can one enter such a nice function into the Deducer package. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return(c(lo,up)` should read `return(c(lo,up))`, and if i copy/paste definition of get_tails in Duducer console, I got the plot, as I would from regular R console.  Is that what you want?

Comment: FYI, you're missing the URL for `[1]`.

Comment: yea right, but can anybody tell me what is the mechanism of the output of that function to the plot? if i run the function with any number it will return the same number. so how can look into the lo, and up number of each x value of the dataset?